# encounter these error - expression must have a constant value

Tags: c++

```
int n;
cout<<"Enter the value of n"<<endl;
cin>>n;
int arr[n];
```

why do I get these error expression must have a constant value

Comment: The value `n` is not constant. Variable-length arrays are not standard C++, hence the error. Instead, use `std::vector` for a dynamically sized container with contiguous memory allocation.

Comment: Specifically here: `#include<vector>` at the beginning and then `std::vector<int> arr(n);` instead of `int arr[n];`. In most situations it is better to use `std:vector` (or maybe `std::array`) than a raw C-style array.